# Citations in interview transcript

Tags: copy-editing

I'm editing an interview transcript. One of the speakers mentions a concept popularized in an academic paper. Would I add the citation within the interview transcript?

Comment: Ask your editor?

Comment: I've only worked with transcripts in a legal context, so I'm not writing an answer, but to me, "transcript" means a faithful written rendition of what was actually said.  Can you write some material to be included before or after the interview transcript itself?  Or as someone suggested, add footnotes?  Endnotes?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend against adding an in-text citation, but you could use a footnote if you think it's important. But it may not be. For example, if you were interviewing someone about current theories on some topic, and the person referred to 8 different theorists in one paragraph, it would disrupt the reading of the text to add all those citations. An interview is what it is---less formal spoken language unburdened by the necessity of validating statements with citations. You can add bracketed changes to a transcript when something is really unclear, but you shouldn't amplify someone's speech because you think it's missing something. Take it as it is and do any amplifying in the following text.

Answer (score 0):

Personally   i   would  an in  text  citation,  but  that's me.  i  despise  footnotes. I  do  end-notes in  addition  to   references.  but that  is  me   and    i  found  putting  footnote into Microsoft  word  extremely  frustrating.  but  that  20  YEARS   ago.   I  wrote   half  my master's  thesis  LONGHAND   while  i  was  snowbound   for  three  days.  Classes  were  cancelled.  Then I had  to  transcribe   that

This  web page Gives   good   reasons  for  WHY  and  how  to   reference  interview  transcripts  for  dissertations:

https://weloty.com/how-to-transcribe-an-interview-for-dissertation-part-1/